# Set hadoop configuration in spark 3.0 - RuntimeException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For hadoop 2.x I was able to configure spark-hadoop using a following snippet:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host", "myhost")
```

However, in spark 3.0 when I try to configure hadoop:

```
session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.driver.host", "myhost")
```

it throws:

````
[info]   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.driver.host;
[info]   at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.requireNonStaticConf(RuntimeConfig.scala:158)```
````

Can you explain me where I am wrong, please?

Answer (score 4):

In spark 3.x, the following property `spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs` newly introduced to reject spark core legacy configuration changes by default (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/d897825d2d0430cb52ae9ac0f6fd742582041682/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala) [line:2353] which is not available in the spark 2.x build.

this is the code snippet of the property,

```
  val SET_COMMAND_REJECTS_SPARK_CORE_CONFS =
    buildConf("spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs")
      .internal()
      .doc("If it is set to true, SET command will fail when the key is registered as " +
        "a SparkConf entry.")
      .version("3.0.0")
      .booleanConf
      .createWithDefault(true)
```

by default when you launch spark 3.x,

```
scala> spark.conf.get("spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs")
res0: String = true
```

which leads to you to mentioned failure with

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host","192.168.93.131")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot modify the value of a Spark config: spark.driver.host;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.requireNonStaticConf(RuntimeConfig.scala:158)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.set(RuntimeConfig.scala:42)
  ... 47 elided
```

**solution:**
try setting up the `spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs,false` then continue changing the `spark.driver.host` property and you can able to change it.

```
scala> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.setCommandRejectsSparkCoreConfs","false")

scala> spark.conf.getAll("spark.driver.host")
res3: String = 192.168.93.131

scala> spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host","192.168.93.132")

scala> spark.conf.set("spark.driver.host","192.168.93.132")
scala> spark.conf.getAll("spark.driver.host")
res6: String = 192.168.93.132
```